# CORS rules coversion from Apache .htaccess to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, cors

Presently I have these .htaccess rules working perfectly on my Apache server:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "https://(www\.)?(domain.com|beta.domain.com|domain.loc)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-CSRF-Token, X-XSRF-TOKEN"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Recent decision to switch to nginx requires us to implement the same. I'm still getting a hang of its internals and really need help converting this into its nginx config counterpart.

**EDIT: What I tried so far:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name api.mydomain.loc;

    root /var/www/mydomain/api/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        if ($http_origin ~* https://(www\.)?(mydomain.loc)) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-CSRF-Token, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
              try_files $uri =404;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might check this out:  https://winginx.com/en/htaccess  It isn't perfect but it gives you a good start.

Comment: Thank you. Checking it out as I go through.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest nginx equivalent of the Apache config in the question would be, just use `add_header` and wrap it all in an`if` block that does a regex match against `$http_origin`:

```
location / {   
  if ($http_origin ~* https://(www\.)?(domain.com|beta.domain.com|domain.loc)) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-CSRF-Token, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
  }
  # use $http_authorization to get the value of the Authorization request header
}
```

The extra `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` stuff that you need to do with Apache isn’t necessary with nginx; instead just use `$http_authorization`.

Note that [variables in nginx that have names prefixed with `$http_`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) are special variables:

`$http_name`
      arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name
      converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

Thus `$http_origin` gives you the value of the `Origin` request header, `$http_authorization` gives you the value of the `Authorization` request header, etc.

Comment: I'm getting this error though: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: For troubleshooting, temporarily first remove the `if` condition completely and then see if it works. That is, just always send the Access-Control-Allow-* headers, regardless of the origin. If that works, then I guess the problem is in the regex against which the `$http_origin` value is being compared, and you’d need to adjust that.

Comment: That's odd. I commented out the condition but retained the rules and it still shows the same error. BTW, i'd like to add that requests returns 200 (success) and result shows up correctly when accessed directly in the browser but empty when accessed via ajax.

Comment: Also, I don't see any `OPTIONS` requests being made. Only `GET` requests shows up on Chrome's Network tab.

Comment: It may not be getting hit because of where you’ve placed it in the config file. Try placing it in a `location / {…}`  block. See the updated answer.