# Making AJAX requests to a CORS-enabled NGINX Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, cors, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to connect to a ReSTful API and for this I need to let the server know that I'm authorized to do so. I'm hosting this ReST API myself and I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy. I've configured NGINX to allow CORS-Requests (through [enable-cors](https://enable-cors.org)). For ease of use, I've decided to use jQuery for the AJAX requests and am using the option to send my credentials.

```
URL = "<url>"
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
}).done(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
})
```

To make a long story short: I am getting the following error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<url>' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

My NGINX configuration is as follows:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
}
if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
}
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
}
```

I understand that I have to find a solution for using this wildcard however, on the network where I am working, IP addresses frequently. So, to come to my question: wat do?

Comment: You can do `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin` but it’s not a good idea to allow requests with credentials from any arbitrary origin. What you’d actually want to do instead is, check that the `$http_origin` value matches some pattern for the origins you want to allow, and if it does, only then do `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin`, and otherwise don’t add that header at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600395/441757 etc.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for the quick reply. To clear any concerns, this server is only accessible from inside the local network. I've applied your suggestion but it gives me the following error: ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<url>' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '<server_ip>'.```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because this:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
```

May conflict with:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

Comment: how does this conflict?

Answer (score -2):

Try `always;`

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range' always;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Can you elaborate a bit? Should I replace something with that? Should I just append this to the NGINX configuration?

Comment: use `always;` in your host Else remove your code and add this