# htaccess Allow Origin Multiple Domains with different Scheme

Tags: .htaccess, cors, access-control, litespeed

I need to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the following domains:

```
http://localhost:8080
app://MyApp
```

This is my current `.htaccess` conditions that I need set for both of the above domains:

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept"
Header Set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Disposition"
```

I already read a lot of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) in SO on this that says to have the server read the Origin header from the client, compare it to the list of domains and then add the values if it matches. However, I am still unable to figure out how will I set my `.htaccess` file so it includes:

1. 2 different domains that uses different scheme
2. Also include `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` with it.
3. I don't want to use `*` unless that is the only option.

Can someone help me rewrite my above `.htaccess` condition to include the 2 domains please.

Comment: I don’t know whether LiteSpeed supports the same range of expressions as Apache, but if it does, you could wrap this into an `<If>` condition that checks the Origin header of the request, and then respond with Header from within that. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: For details on how to write the Apache config, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600395/441757 and/or — if you’re not including authentication credentials (and also to ensure you’re handling the CORS preflight OPTIONS request) — the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42558499/441757

Comment: Why, exactly, don’t you want to just use the `*` wildcard? What specifically would you be trying to prevent by not using the `*` wildcard? Unless you’re allowing authentication credentials to be included in the request, there is no real-world problem in practice that you’d be avoiding by not just using the `*` wildcard. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154277/441757.

Comment: Thank you for your response @sideshowbarker. The reason I want to avoid * is because I want to allow auth credentials and in some requests the use of cookies, etc and I thought the * might have issues with it. Is there a way to add this into the htaccess itself without editing the Litespeed config file?

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you for your comments. Your links helped me in putting together the `.htaccess` rules for my scenario. I didnt want to edit the Litespeed config file directly since it is easier to quickly edit the htaccess files rules than litespeed config. Your links gave me the idea and have added what I did as the answer. It seems to work now and hopefully my users dont have issues with this rule.

Comment: @Neel — Cheers, glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added Multiple Domains with different Scheme along with a check on origin to send back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other headers with it based on the request origin. I did not want to edit the LiteSpeed config file directly. The following rules in my `.htaccess` seems to work:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "(http(s)?://localhost:8080)|(app://MyApp)|(app://myapp)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept"
    Header add Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Disposition"
    Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```